# Clutch engages lower after mechanic repaired slave cylinder. Can I adjust this to what it was?

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission

**Disclaimer: I have a very basic understanding of clutch and master/slave cylinder. (i.e. I know it's a basic hydraulic system)**

**Car: 2000 Hyundai accent**

A year ago, I had my car towed in when it was no longer able to shift into gear. My mechanic replaced the slave cylinder and I was able to shift and drive, but shifting has never felt the same since (more sticky). I often have to remove the thicker floor mat so I can engage the clutch enough to get into gear, or else it'll grind or stick.

Could this be easily adjusted, or could there be other things going on that were never resolved/identified?

NOTE: I've bled the clutch hydraulics according to the repair manual from bleeder valve on slave cylinder. No change major change.

Comment: I'd think the problem might be the master/slave needs to be bled better. There's no real way to adjust the hydraulics to my knowledge.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'm wondering if that might be it (My mechanic isn't known for being 100% thorough). I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, I did 4 clutch depressions to bleed from the slave cylinder. No major change here.